# Auto-responder with Scheduled Reminder emails

Tags: civimail, scheduled-reminders

When sending an email via Civimail, it is possible to have any replies receive an auto-responder message saying that the email address is unattended or not monitored. Is this possible for Scheduled Reminders?

I've just discovered that members have been replying to our membership renewal reminders and we haven't been checking that email account.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider resetting/customizing your reminder.
You can then define the use of an auto-reply message in the tab "reactions" in CiviMail.

Comment: Reminders are configured from the 'Schedule Reminder' screen in admin. Or if I edit the template there, will the 'reactions' settings be saved for use as a scheduled reminder?